# Databinding does not update property value on back navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Binding works fine when I first navigate to a page containing the code above. Then I navigate forward to a page that that makes changes to the model (the Name property) and navigate back (with back key). The Text property, however, is still displaying the old value. How can I force the bound value to update on back navigation.

Comment: Does the first page definitely have access to the *same* (now changed) model? If you add a break point to the `Name` property, can you see whether it's being fetched when you navigate back?

Comment: Does your class implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event within the setter of the Name property?
Can you add code for the OnNavigatedTo and the code for your model?

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot
No it did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I added this in my model and it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I've added that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your model implements INotifyPropertyChanged and that the PropertyChanged event is firing within the setter of Name